# Retrofit support SNI

Tags: android, retrofit, retrofit2, androidhttpclient

I have question. Does retrofit support SSL with use SNI? It's a technique that allows servers to return different SSL certificates depending on the requested host name, which allows using SSL in shared hosting scenarios.

Comment: have you got the answer for the question? If yes, please post the answer. Thanks

Comment: Take a look here: http://square.github.io/okhttp/ You can use it with retrofit and it works :)